# Include product images and description automatically in a MySQL database from a excel tabel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to build an ecommerce site with PHP and MySQL, but I have over 9000 products which I have to add. Is there any way I could do this automatically? I mean I have an excel spreadsheet from the supplier with price, description and a code for each product. Is there any way the images would be uploaded based on that code, without download them in the images folder manually one by one? And to get the description in the same way? OScommerce has something like this? Because if it does I will swith to it. Thank you so much for all your answers!

Comment: Have you tried using any of the PHP libraries for reading Excel files to see if they can help you?

Comment: @MarkBaker no I haven't. I'm still a noob at PHP. But I will look ito it. Thank you!

Comment: Are the images embedded in your Excel?  Do they existing in a folder and are they named with your product ID?

Comment: @panofish For images I have a code. For example, if you google X7-200MP you should find a mouse pad. I want to add one of the images found on google in my database, but without me downloading it and saveing it in the images folder manually. This should be done automatically, if possible. I couldn't find any solution on the internet for this problem and I don't know if it's possible. That's why I decided asking here

Comment: There are 100's of images in google images for X7-200MP.  How would the software know which to pick and which one you had the rights to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the .xls(x) file to a .csv and then use the php function **fgetcsv** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read through the file line-by-line. As you read each row, dump that row's data into the database table. As far as the images, I don't know exactly what you mean. Perhaps you could shed some more light on that aspect.

Example taken from php.net:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: If an Excel file contains embedded images, then these will be lost when converting to a CSV file